# Accessing two synchronized block with two thread simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Could anyone tell me how to accessing one method simultaneously with 2 thread, this method have 2 parameter and 2 synchronized block. and what I want is, one thread execute first synchronized block, and the other thread execute the second synchronized block.

```
public class myThread{

public static class TwoSums implements Runnable{
    private int sum1 = 0;
    private int sum2 = 0;

    public void add(int a, int b){
        synchronized(this){
            sum1 += a;
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Thread name that was accessing this code 1  : "+name);
        }

        synchronized(this){
            sum2 += b;
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Thread name that was accessing this code 2 : "+name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        add(10,20);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoSums task = new TwoSums();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(task, "Thread 1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task, "Thread 2");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

}

This code containing some code from : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/race-conditions-and-critical-sections.html

Comment: The second thread cannot get to the second synchronized block without executing the first one first...

Comment: Divide your method into 2 different methods.

Comment: so it means i can't accessing 2 synchronized block with 2 thread in one method ?

Comment: How can you jump direct to 7th line in your method?

Comment: oh ok, i get it. so in other words it impossible to get result like what i expected

Comment: @Okem It's easy to get a result as you expect, but it's impossible to do what you're trying to do in Java, to get that result. You're "thinking wrong", at least as far as Java is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are processed sequentially by any thread and the synchronization blocks don't make any exception. The following code does what you are asking for but looks just as an exercise without any real meaningful application

```
public static class TwoSums implements Runnable {
    private int sum1 = 0;
    private int sum2 = 0;

    public void add(int a, int b) {
        if ("Thread 1".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
            synchronized (this) {
                sum1 += a;
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Thread name that was accessing this code 1  : " + name);
            }
        }
        if ("Thread 2".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
            synchronized (this) {
                sum2 += b;
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Thread name that was accessing this code 2 : " + name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        add(10, 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that goal (I'm not going to discuss if what you're doing is right or wrong because I suppose that you're just learning how things work) you need to use the ReentranLock interface and its implementation Lock class:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

You should declare this object in your TwoSum class and use the lock object inside of your add method. ReentrantLock interface has a method called tryLock which will try to get the lock of the object where it's called and it will return a boolean value true if it was successful or false otherwise. So for the first thread it will return true, but for the second one it will return false. So all you need to put is a validation

```
if(lock.tryLock()) //Execute block code 1
else // Execute block code 2
```